# PHP/MySQL Redirect page if table value is 0

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check a database value assigned to a user account and redirect when loading a page if the value is 0 (or less than 1?)

code is have for the function is:

```
// ******************************************************
// JAY CHECK SCREENINGS FUNCTION  
function CheckScreenings() {

if (!empty($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    $conn = connectToDB();

        if (!$conn) {  die('Could not connect: ' . $conn->errorInfo());  }
    $checkquery = ("SELECT screenings FROM screener_users WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['userId'] . "';");
    foreach ($conn->query($checkquery) as $row)
        {
            $screenings = $row[0];
        }

    if ($screenings == 0)
    {
        header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
        die();  
    } 
 }
}
// ******************************************************
```

I also, on another page need to hide 2 hyperlinks if this same value is 0.

```
<li>
   <a href="/screener-test">Take a new test</a>
</li>
<li style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <?php $lastTest = getUserLatestIncompleteTest($user_id); ?>                            
  <a href="/screener-test?test_id=<?php echo $lastTest[0]; ?>">Continue last incomplete test</a>
</li>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
J

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: does not seem to be picking out the $screenings  - always seeing it as 0 and running the code in the if screenings==0 section.

Comment: make sure your `$conn->query($checkquery)` function return an array

Comment: Check your $row[0] values and be aware that $screenings holds the value of the last record because you are overwriting this value with every run of the for-loop

Comment: To complete the comment of RST: the fact that you loop on all your rows and do nothing with their values except overwriting a variable with it, shows some kind of functionnal issue with your code. Only the last row value will be kept and used further. This doesnt sound logical at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your functions do what I think they do, something written like

```
$result_rows = $conn->query($checkquery);
if (count(result_rows) == 0) {
    header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
}
```

Should work.